# What could be causing this Access Denied error?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, process, directory

**Edit:** Using "Documents" instead of "My Documents" gets rid of the error. I was also recommended to use the Windows special folders instead of absolute paths.

I'm attempting to replace all the shortcuts on my desktop with an application I'm writing that will have its own version of the shortcuts. I plan to give the new shortcuts some of the same functionality as the old ones. Before doing anything else, I figured opening the file or folder that the shortcut points to would be important. Here's a sample piece of code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Process p1, p2, p3, p4;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        p1 = new Process();
        p2 = new Process();
        p3 = new Process();
        p4 = new Process();

        p1.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
        p2.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\Users\\Cheese\\My Documents";
        p3.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\Users\\Cheese\\AppData";
        p4.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\Program Files (x86)";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p1.Start();
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p2.Start();
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p3.Start();
    }
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p4.Start();
    }

}
```

[image: Access Denied error]

This is on Windows 7 Home Premium. I'm getting the error while debugging in Visual C# 2010 Express. I've opened several other folders like System32, AppData, and various folders on another partition on the same drive. I was able to open various music files and run different programs. Everything seems to work fine except for My Documents. I would think that the Windows folder would have greater restrictions than the default location for personal files. I'm thinking it's not really a permissions thing, but I can't even guess what might be the issue. I can open My Documents with explorer. I can move files to and from the directory.

This seems like such a simple thing. I know that there's a lot I don't fully understand about how Windows works, but this situation and a few others are making me think that maybe I don't really know much of anything about Windows. What are some good books or web resources that I can look into to get a good grasp of this operating system? Possibly with a focus on file management and system privileges from a novice's point of view?

Comment: Under Windows 7 "My Documents" is a Junction link to "Documents", it could be a process launch problem with the junction.  do you get the same error with launching "c:\\Users\\Cheese\\Documents"?

Comment: Have you tried to find that folder in your user profile?

Comment: It's almost pathetic how simple the solution was. Using "Documents" instead of "My Documents" works.

Comment: I've added an answer as my comment was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented,

Under Windows 7 "My Documents" is a Junction link to "Documents", trying to launch the process on a junction will fail with this error. Launch "c:\Users\Cheese\Documents" instead.

Or if this the current users my documents folder you should really ask the system for its path.

```
var path=System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should never use these hardcoded paths.
The right way to go with that is the Environment.SpecialFolder enum coupled with Environment.GetFolderPath() like this

```
string myDocumentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

Other 'SpecialFolder' enums can be [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

It's very important to use the **GetFolderPath** together with the SpecialFolder enum because it returns the locations correctly adjusted for the different operating systems, the localization of the operating system and the change that the user can do on some of these locations.

Comment: In my code above, is this (special folders) the reason "cmd" is able to launch without any path specified? I didn't even have the extension in the file name.

Comment: The cmd.exe is the command shell interpreter and is located in a folder included in the system PATH environment variable. So the operating system check each folder in the PATH searching for a program (bat,cmd,com or exe) that starts with CMD. It will be the same if you try with "notepad".

Answer (score 1):

With Windows 7 "My Documents" has been renamed simply to "Documents". See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Documents).
The path you try to open does not exist in your OS.

Comment: Well it does technically exist, its just that its a junction point, which fails when you try and launch it as a process.

Comment: I do not think so. At least dir does not display anything like this. And the junction sysinternals command does also not find any junctions there. But if you navigate below My Documents and right click on the a file inside My Documents you will see that the path is indeed ..\Documents\... Windows 7 does not create a My Documents junction but Explorer itself does dispaly a translated folder name for the users. On my German machine it is called "Eigene Dokumente" and there is certainly no such folder there.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder - This link shows %USERPROFILE%\Documents for the location of the Special Folder for "My Documents". It then has a table at the bottom showing Virtual Folders. "My Documents" exists as a virtual folder as well. **"Virtual folder of the user's My Documents folder; used as a child of the Desktop virtual folder"** I have a decent idea of what Special and Virtual folders do, but I'm not quite understanding how My Documents can be both.

Comment: @AloisKraus In a command prompt, change to c:\users\<your username> and type "dir /a My*".  You will see that it lists my documents as a junction.

Comment: @Cheese My Documents is not both.  There are two "My Documents" one is a special folder one is a Virtual folder.

Comment: dir /a c:\Users\Alois\My* does show nothing. The reason is that the junction name is localized and it is called "Eigene Dateien". It is therefore not safe to use My Documents as shortcut programatically since depending on the OS language it is different.